# How dow I implement AffirmativeBased object in Spring Security 4?

Tags: spring, spring-security

In [Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html#AffirmativeBased(java.util.List)), the constructor looked like this:

```
public AffirmativeBased(List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters)
```

In [Spring 4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html#AffirmativeBased(java.util.List)), the constructor adds a type:

```
public AffirmativeBased(List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters)
```

Can someone help me understand what it's looking for?

Comment: Nothing special. It's just compiler `generics warning` fix. As you see it continues to be so generic that you don't need to worry about restrictions for `AccessDecisionVoter` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is all fine. If you are using spring boot/java config, just change your declaration(add a ? type) as below so that the compiler does not complain. Anyway all the type info will be *erased*.

```
List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> voters = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.List] found for dependency
>   [java.util.List>]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I was able to fix it by changing the property to a constructor argument.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">


    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <util:list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
                </bean>
            </util:list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

read the source..  take a look at GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

```
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>>();
    ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
    expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());
    if (prePostEnabled()) {
        decisionVoters
                .add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
    }
    if (jsr250Enabled()) {
        decisionVoters.add(new Jsr250Voter());
    }
    decisionVoters.add(new RoleVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
    return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
}
```